# Use jQuery for defining variable in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to JQuery while defining a variable in PHP.

Suppose I have the following `index.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../resources/js/common/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bigdaddy">
        <div class="daddy">
            <header class="main"></header>
            <main>
                <aside>
                </aside>
                <article>
                    <div class="div1">
                        Sample1
                    </div>
                    <div class="div2">
                        <div> //Child 1
                            Sample2
                        </div>
                        <p> //Child 2
                            Sample3
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        // the code
                    ?>
                </article>
            </main>
            <footer class="main"></footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Questions:

- How can I select `<div>` with attribute and attribute value `class="div1"` to get its node/inner text?
- How can I select `<p>` child of `<div class="div2">` its node/inner text?
- Is it even possible to use jQuery in PHP?

Both questions are using jQuery

I thought of

```
<?php
    $answer1 = $('div[class="div1"]').html();
    echo $answer1;
    $answer2 = $('div.class="div2"').children('p').html();
    echo $answer2;
?>
```

But it didn't work.

Expected result should be:

Sample1
Sample3

**EDIT: I can't use AJAX.**

Comment: Is it even possible? Should've been first question.

Comment: Your code is not working because you are trying to use jQuery in PHP. If  you need to pass values to PHP you should to get them via jQuery and use ajax to pass them to PHP script.

Comment: No its not possible. Or at least not how you try. You can't use Javascript inside of PHP. Javascript is running clientside, PHP is serverside. They can't communicate the way you try. You have to pass the values from JS to PHP with for example AJAX.
Edit: Blady was faster :D

Comment: You need to understand the client and server. all the javascript/jquery code runs in browser which happens very late as the response from the server already ran and displayed at browser.

Comment: Edit: added question "is it possible" so everyone can actually answer.

Comment: @alej27 what you are trying to do is not possible unless you use ajax to send data back to server.

Comment: Do you know then how could I select  the inner HTML of `<p>` inside `<div class="div2">`? Using PHP.

Comment: @alej27, why can't you use AJAX, if you use jQuery you can use AJAX also so your edit to the question is invalid as long as you use jQuery.

Comment: "Edit: I can't use AJAX." Why? You're using JQuery too. So it won't be a problem of the system. The only reason why I can imagine you wrote this is that you've never heard about AJAX or you're simply to lazy to read more about it to learn it. There's really no good reason why you shouldn't be able to use it. If I'm wrong, correct me.

Comment: Have you put it inside `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: Take a read at this: http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/ClientSide01CD/page_18.htm

Comment: I know AJAX. I was using it, but Google bot wasn't obtaining the content generated from it. I asked about that [in this Google products forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/oouCcKurc1Y). [**This is**](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-TfOjlmeddYk/WGxGw1SrG-I/AAAAAAAAH2o/g-Hcy9M_KqEBF6eCNwk6JU08tvdVmqvUACLcB/s1600/page-viewed-by-user.png) how my website looks like, but [**this is**](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-X_BvY9a4mFM/WGxIe9VJLGI/AAAAAAAAH20/21W_t-n3cfEvXumlTBa7qPhG1j-XvgtfwCLcB/s1600/page-viewed-by-googlebot-desktop.png) how Google sees it.

Comment: @alej27, if this is a SEO problem you need to know that this is offtopic for this website.

Comment: In their tour page (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) they say this page is about programming questions. Why is this offtopic? Where do you suggest to ask it?

Comment: @alej27, SEO questions should be asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ tagged with `seo`

Comment: Still it isn't a SEO problem, not only. I'm visiting the website on mobile and it isn't loading (only on iPhone, not on Android nor Windows Phone). **However**, on desktop is fine. So it could be a SEO **and** mobile problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX to send the data you want to the server, and handle the rest using PHP:

```
var answer1 = $('.div1').text();
var answer2 = $('.div2').find('p').text();
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'your_php_script.php',
  data: {
    answer1 : answer1, answer2: answer2
  },
  success: function(response_from_php_script) {
    console.log(response_from_php_script);
  }
});
```

And in your PHP script you can get the value of the paragraph you need like this:

```
 $answer1 = $_POST['answer1'];
 echo $answer1;
 $answer2 = $_POST['answer2'];
 echo $answer2;
```

Of course you will have to sanitize the post values if you want to insert it in the database, but that's a whole new thing.

I hope this will get you started.

You can read more about AJAX **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**.

Comment: @A.Lau, saw that, but as long as he uses jQuery I don't see why can't he use AJAX.